# css circle gets oval on browser zoom

Tags: css, sass, zooming

I created radio buttons via css. Just styled on the pseudo-elements like this:
https://codepen.io/emily-green/pen/MWYQZqz

Here is the html

```
<label class="wrapper">
  <input type="radio" />
  <div class="label">Text</div>
</label>

<label class="wrapper wrapper--checked">
  <input type="radio" />
  <div class="label">Text</div>
</label>
```

Here is my css

```
input {
  display: none
}

.wrapper {
    font-family: "arial";
    align-items: center;
    color: #00f;
    display: flex;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 600;
    justify-items: center;
    padding: .5rem 0 .5rem 1.3rem;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    white-space: nowrap;

  &::before,
  &::after {
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 14px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 14px;
  }

  &::before {
    border: 2px solid #00f;
  }

  &::after {
    background: #000;
    transform: scale( 0 );
  }

  // checked
  &--checked {
    color: #000;

    &::after {
      transform: scale( .4 );
    }
  }
}
```

My problem:
When I zoom with the browser and on Windows Edge, the inner circle is misplaced or the outer circle gets oval. Does anyone have a solution for it?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website OR off-site example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Thanks for the information I changed it

Answer (score 0):

I didn't found a solution for it so I changed it to an inline SVG. Inline because otherwise, the SVG get quite pixelated on some browsers